# How to get all addresses of a recipient in Outlook using .Net/C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to get all the email Ids that belong to a person in Outlook. When I look at a contacts properties in Outlook, I can see several email addresses listed - SIM, SMTP and smtp. Is there a way to get all of these? I know how to get the primary email address using:

```
recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

which always seem to give the email address marked "SMTP". I want "smtp" and "SIP" email addresses too. This is Outlook 2010 connected to Exchange server and all users are exchange users only.

Thanks in advance
Vikram

Comment: do a `MSDN Google Search` on the following and it will take you here read the documentation it has examples on getting user information
[C# MSDN AddressEntry.GetExchagneUser Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser.aspx)

Comment: Thanks MethodMan. So far, I have found out that this information should be available if I use PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. But I cant seem to find what is the value I should use in GetProperty for "smtp", "SMTP" and "SIP" addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer! Thanks to MethodMan for pointing in the right direction.

const string PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101E";

```
var addresses = recipient.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES);
```

That gives the list of all available addresses for a contact!