# How to get the recipients from email

Tags: c#, selenium, outlook

I'm using Outlook.Interop in order to to get the Html Body from email recieved.
I'm trying to get the recipients' email address, but only getting a name of the recipients and not the full email address.

```html
 Application myApp = new ApplicationClass();
            NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Folders["digitel"];

            List<MailItem> ReceivedEmails = new List<MailItem>();
            
            foreach (MailItem mail in myInbox.Items)
            { ReceivedEmails.Add(mail); }

            var Recipients = ReceivedEmails[0].Recipients.ToString();
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868695.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all addresses of a recipient in Outlook using .Net/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410811/how-to-get-all-addresses-of-a-recipient-in-outlook-using-net-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the following snippet:

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in ReceivedEmails[0].Recipients)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.ToSt‌​‌​ring());
}
```

Let me know if you have any problem :)!

Comment: I'm getting an error:
The property "PR_SMTP_ADDRESS" cannot be parsed or has an invalid format.
as you can see, I already tried using it as a string.

Comment: Check `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress `

Comment: can you please give me an example of how should I use it?

Comment: ok I did it.
var Reciepients = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString();

Please post a new answer so I could mark it as one.

Comment: this one worked for me (with C#)
var Reciepients = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.ToSt‌​ring(); 
so please post an answer and I'll mark it as one

Comment: @YanivEliav Actually it's the same as the last one i added i just missed the `()` in `GetExchangeUser`. Anyways update ;)